# Java Blocking queue find, get and remove

Tags: java, concurrency

In the blocking queue, do we have API to achieve this requirement, if one object (say, a String) is inside a queue, return it and then remove it from queue.

Certainly, we can loop the queue and do if-else one by one, if not matched, put it back to queue. Do we have a better way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean if you can de-queue a specific message of many from the queue based on the contents of its payload?

Comment: thanks. very simple, find it, return it and remove it from the queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to do comparison based on equality (`equals` method) then you can use the [`remove(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method of a `BlockingQueue` to remove the object.

E.g.

```
BlockingQueue<String> myQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
myQueue.add("hello");
myQueue.add("goodbye");
System.out.println("Queue contains goodbye: " + myQueue.contains("goodbye"));

myQueue.remove("goodbye");
System.out.println("Queue contains goodbye: " + myQueue.contains("goodbye"));
```

If you need to remove an object based on some other criteria, then you must iterate the queue using the available iterator.  Depending on the particular implementing queue, the iterator may or may not support the `remove` operation (check the documentation for the particular class).  `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` both have iterators that support `remove`, and in fact the implementation of `ArrayBlockingQueue.remove(Object o)` simply calls and uses its own iterator and iterator.remove.

E.g.

```
BlockingQueue<String> myQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
myQueue.add("hello");
myQueue.add("goodbye");
System.out.println("Queue contains goodbye: " + myQueue.contains("goodbye"));

Iterator<String> iterator = myQueue.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    if (iterator.next().contains("good")) iterator.remove();
}
System.out.println("Queue contains goodbye: " + myQueue.contains("goodbye"));
```

If the queue's iterator supports `remove` then this is a much more optimal solution than removing and re-adding all of the other queue elements (especially in the case of a linked list based queue).

Comment: thanks. the remove method will return boolean, this is not what I want, I need it to return the matched object and then remove it.

Comment: @user595234 Then you will have to use the iterator (if remove is supported on it).

Answer (score 0):

BlockingQueue interface and all its implementations have a method called `remove(Object o)` which removes single instance of specified element from this queue. You can use this method on the BlockingQueue implementation which stores your string data andyou can remove one object.